# GraalVM build failure with "Blocklisted methods are reachable for runtime compilation"

Tags: java, graalvm

Thank you for your time to help me with my problem. I'm a JAVA beginner but I'm very interested in this language. So I've been learning how to use its frameworks recently, but as you can see, I'm currently facing some problems from graalvm. I know it's silly, but what I want to ask is how to add or delete methods in blocklist from it's truffle polyglot engine.

I have try to add [-H:-TruffleCheckBlockListMethods](https://github.com/SpamanDev/StoreChain-Server/blob/f74bd9d47a23d2dbebbe3cbd0dd620fbd373e5e6/pom.xml#L363) but it's not seem to work without `-Dtruffle.TruffleRuntime=com.oracle.truffle.api.impl.DefaultTruffleRuntime`,  but with truffle runtime set will slow performance real bad. Any help please !

[CI Report](https://github.com/SpamanDev/StoreChain-Server/runs/4755546198?check_suite_focus=true#step:9:302)

I have read the [source](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/3f97c4912642f1f214758aa98332a27f05d86e7a/substratevm/src/com.oracle.svm.truffle/src/com/oracle/svm/truffle/TruffleFeature.java#L665) code from GitHub, they just add those [functions](https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/3f97c4912642f1f214758aa98332a27f05d86e7a/substratevm/src/com.oracle.svm.truffle/src/com/oracle/svm/truffle/TruffleFeature.java#L524) into blocklist, WHY ??

Comment: When you are a Java beginner, you should start with learning the language and how to write Java programs. GraalVM is neither a fundamental part of the Java language nor required for using Java.

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to use [truffle boundary](https://www.graalvm.org/truffle/javadoc/index.html?com/oracle/truffle/api/CompilerDirectives.TruffleBoundary.html)